# Horizontal vs. Vertical centric email signatures

Tags: email, screen-resolution

When it comes to company signatures you can be forced to use their approved format which I understand. Outside of that, or where you have choice, are there considerations as far as horizontally or vertically heavy email signatures? Consider the following examples made using dummy data from fakenamegenerator.com and freelogodesign.org

#### Vertically focused example

[image: Vertical focused signature example]

#### Horizontally focused example

[image: Horizontally focused signature example]

Assuming all of the content you see in both examples was required would either have disadvantages? These would be used internally on Outlook but be communicate to external folks. The horizontal example is based on a table.

I feel the vertical one would have a better chance of always being rendered the same regardless of the client / device. Whereas the the horizontal one might be forcibly wrapped or scaled to fit on smaller screens. The horizontal one could look better on wider screens and takes up less horizontal space to as to not drown a simple correspondence with a signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer would be based on saving vertical space: chose the horizontal one. Emails can take a lot of vertical space and a vertically long signature can make the email seem even longer. **(Argument for horizontal application)**

However thing are not always that simple, if your logo doesn't have a nice square or vertical application it can look awkward as it does in the imagens you posted. In you example the "Pragmantys" logo application is very horizontal, in this case it doesn't sit well with the horizontal application because it is not as "tall" as the content and it is visually disbalanced. **(Argument for vertical application)**

Having said that, I'd go with the vertical signature if chosing between the two you presented.

But if there was a more square/vertical application of your logo I'd prefer that on a horizontal application as demonstrated below.

[image: Example of ideal application]

*(Obs.: I've modified your logo freely to show you an example, but you should check with your designer if there is an existing application like this and if you can use it. I don't recommend you just change your logo without properly documenting is as a new application for future use)*

Answer (score 1):

I would add another consideration to [Caê Penna's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/112803). Gmail Workspace allows me to remove images in emails from unknown senders. In this situation, the **vertical layout** is likely to show up better, because the logo will be reduced to a single broken link. Something like this:

[image: Sample email signature with missing logo]